# Octave program to solve ODE

Tags: octave, ode

I have an **ODE**

```
dy=x dx,  y(0)=2
```

The solution of this equation is `y =x^2/2 + K.`

```
K become 2.
```

Now I have to plot graph. 
When

```
 x=0, y=2
 x=1, y=2.5
 x=2, y=4
 x=3, y=6.5
 x=4, y=10
```

I have to write an `Octave program` to generate these values

My code is **test.m**

```
function xdot = f (x,t)
 xdot=x;
 endfunction
 x=lsode("f",2,(t=linspace(0,4,5)));
 #plot(t,x)
 x
```

I run the pgm in cmd but it gives

```
2.0000
5.4366
14.7781
40.1711
109.1963
```

The expected result is

```
2
2.5
4
6.5
10
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer..

Use

`xdot=t;`

instead of

`xdot=x;`